# VSC++ create a class and run functions from dll without the .h

Tags: visual-c++, dll

I have a old dll that i need to use for a legacy code.
I don't have it's original Headers but i know the name of the class and signatures of the functions that i want to call.

Is there a way for me to call the class instantiation and the functions of the dll if i don't have it's compaining header file?

Comment: You could try and write your own header with a fake class definition, with the right constructor and member function signatures. Mark the definition with `__declspec(dllimport)`. You need to at least know (or guess at) the size of the class instance; you can fake it by giving the class a `char` array of sufficient size as a private member. Might work.

Comment: Also make a plan to replace it ASAP... a black-box DLL with no source built in ancient days is a recipe for security issues, unfixable bugs, and is what appcompat nightmares are made from...

Comment: Is this a C++ class or a COM interface? If it's an interface, you can probably fake it enough to get it to work IFF the API is really simple.

Comment: About replacingmi can't. A client of mine use the output of it and he can't replace the other end point.About the size i figured i would have to handle it.I saw : www.codeproject.com/Articles/9405/Using-classes-exported-from-a-DLL-using-LoadLi‌​brar and it should theoretically work but i don't think it will be effective, i am pursuing another way of achieve my goals since creating the headers even though possible will not actually work